# Activiti REST API not retrieving tasks anymore

Tags: java, spring, activiti

After a couple of years of normal operations, the API of Activiti 5.17.0 to retrieve tasks is not returning the latest tasks anymore.
The API invoked is a GET to `/runtime/tasks?includeProcessVariables=true&size=600000&order=desc` with basic authentication.

Nobody changed it, but it is just stuck at returning tasks from 10 days ago.
I checked the Activiti tables and they contain the records for the tasks I need to retrieve.

I also tried to cleanup some old data from `act_hi_taskinst` and `act_ru_task` and from , supposing it was a matter of cardinality (maybe too many tasks), but nothing changed.

I also tried to increase the size parameter in the request, but nothing changes (not reaching that limit).

What is going on?

--- Edit

It seems a matter of IDs. If I try to get the last 10 tasks order by create_time_ desc, only tasks until ID 999907 are returned. The next ID is over 1.000.000 and I can see it in the database, but the API is not returning it.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the order by: ordering by id (which is a varying char in the database) is counterintuitive. In fact, when order by `id_ desc` the tasks with ID over 1.000.000 are AFTER tasks 900.000.
Putting the size to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` did not fix the problem, for some reason I don't get (maybe the reason is inside Activiti query building code).

BTW I changed the order and used `createTime desc`. This was, most recent tasks are returned regardless of their ID.

Here's my custom-tailored controller (to be improved, but working for my specific use case).

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/")
public class CustomRest extends TaskBaseResource {

    @Autowired
    TaskService taskService;

    /*
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "custom")
    public List<Task> retrieveAllTasks() {
        return taskService.createTaskQuery().includeProcessVariables().active().list();
    }
     */
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "custom")
    public DataResponse getTasks(@RequestParam Map<String, String> requestParams, HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        // Create a Task query request
        TaskQueryRequest request = new TaskQueryRequest();

        // Populate filter-parameters
        if (requestParams.containsKey("name")) {
            request.setName(requestParams.get("name"));
        }

        request.setIncludeProcessVariables(true);
        request.setActive(true);

        return getTasksFromQueryRequest(request, requestParams);
    }

    protected DataResponse getTasksFromQueryRequest(TaskQueryRequest request,
                                                    Map<String, String> requestParams) {

        TaskQuery taskQuery = taskService.createTaskQuery();
        taskQuery.active();
        taskQuery.includeProcessVariables();


        HashMap<String, QueryProperty> properties = new HashMap<String, QueryProperty>();

        properties.put("id", TaskQueryProperty.TASK_ID);
        properties.put("name", TaskQueryProperty.NAME);
        properties.put("description", TaskQueryProperty.DESCRIPTION);
        properties.put("dueDate", TaskQueryProperty.DUE_DATE);
        properties.put("createTime", TaskQueryProperty.CREATE_TIME);
        properties.put("priority", TaskQueryProperty.PRIORITY);
        properties.put("executionId", TaskQueryProperty.EXECUTION_ID);
        properties.put("processInstanceId", TaskQueryProperty.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID);
        properties.put("tenantId", TaskQueryProperty.TENANT_ID);

        request.setSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        //request.setSize(10);
        request.setOrder("createTime");
        request.setOrder("desc");

        DataResponse paginatedList = new TaskPaginateList(restResponseFactory).paginateList(
                requestParams, request, taskQuery, "createTime", properties);


        return paginatedList;
    }
}
```